# Implenting A Rest Web service with Java or C#

Tags: c#, java, rest

We are about to implement a Web Service component and we are making a discussion regarding the language that we are going to implement it. It will be either C# or Java. Some of us are supporting Java while other members of the team are supporting C# mainly based on our experience and previous knowledge . Which of these two languages would be the better approach? Answer should consider issues such as Hosting and Deployment. Also please do not turn this in another war between these 2 great languages

Thank you

Comment: *"Also please do not turn this in another war between these 2 great languages"*: That's exactly the reason why your question is off topic here. There is no authoritative answer. Instead, all answers are subjective.

Comment: Again it is against my intentions to start a flame war. I need answers from people that will arguing for one or the other option. According to their argument we will make a legitimate desicion

Comment: The rules here declare opinion-based questions as off-topic, because they usually degrade into a flame-war, *no matter* the intention of the OP.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there is any technological challenge of creating Rest based services in any of the language either C# or Java.

It mostly depends upon the skill set and echo system of your company. If you are already working in .net and windows stack and have developer with the same skill set then you can choose Asp.net WebApi otherwise you can go for JAVA.